# Can an external source be used in place of a proxy contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, gas

The recommended way to create updatable contracts is to create a proxy contract which then calls an origial contract. I haven’t worked with proxy contracts yet, but I’ve seen the code and it appeared to be complex for such a simple task.

Instead, why not store a file with the address of a smart contract in IPFS, and then fetch a file from a proxy contract? Whenever a smart contract is updated, edit a file in IPFS to reflect a change. This way, code will become way simpler and may not even require a proxy contract.

Comment: In that case another contract couldn't use your contract, they can't read the IPFS content directly because it is off-chain.

Comment: Why do you assume that code for fetching a file from IPFS is way simpler than the code to call another contract from the proxy?

Comment: @lenin I don't assume, I know. it's 1 line

Comment: Elaborate. Which "my contract" - proxy one or original one? Why not? And what is the **it** in "it's off-chain" you mean?

Comment: @kennya Can you show an implementation? How does a contract read from IPFS?